# Scrapy Spider returns None instead of Item

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

**I've found the answer, down below. In short, wrong Indentation in the ItemPipeline caused it to return None.**

I've been trying to write a CrawlSpider in Scrapy, having never worked with python before. The Spider crawls,calls the callback function, extracts data and fills the item, but it always returns None. I've tested it with a print article call, everything was in order. I have tried this both with yield and return ( though I still don't understand the difference). Frankly, I'm out of ideas. Down below is the callback function.//edit added the spider code as well

```
class ZeitSpider(CrawlSpider):
name= xxxx
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/%d/%d' %(JAHR,39)]
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@class="teaserlist"]/li[@class="archiveteaser"]/h4[@class="title"]')),callback='parse_url',follow=True),)


    def parse_url(self,response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        article = Article()

        article['url']= response.url.encode('UTF-8',errors='strict')

        article['author']= hxs.select('//div[@id="informatives"]/ul[@class="tools"]/li[@class="author first"]/text()').extract().pop().encode('UTF-8',errors='strict')
        article['title']= hxs.select('//div[@class="articleheader"]/h1/span[@class="title"]/text()').extract().pop().encode('UTF-8',errors='strict')

        article['text']= hxs.select('//div[@id="main"]/p/text()').extract().pop().encode('UTF-8',errors='strict')

        article['excerpt'] = hxs.select('//p[@class="excerpt"]/text()').extract().pop().encode('UTF-8',errors='strict')
        yield article
```

and the item definition

```
class Article(Item):
    url=Field()
    author=Field()
    text=Field()
    title=Field()
    excerpt=Field()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after stepping through the program with pdb I found the error:

Because I have multiple spiders, I wanted to write multiple ItemPipelines. To make them differentiate per Spider, I added an

```
if spider.name=='SpiderName'
    return item
```

Notice the Indentation. The Pipeline returned Nothing, and so the output became None.

After changing the Indentation, the spider worked flawlessly. Another example of PEBCAC .

Comment: THANK YOU. Error message was `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'`. Maybe it can help Google redirect here.